# Getting undefined in BehaviourSubject subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to subscribe to a `BehaviourSubject` that was set by parent component and get it in the child one, i'm trying to make the following in my component:

```
export class ModuliComponent implements OnInit {
  public profilo: Profilo;

  constructor(public profiloService: ProfiloService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.profiloService.dataProfilo.subscribe(data => this.profilo = data); // setting profilo
  }

}
```

But when i try to use `profilo` in HTML i just get `undefined` on `asporto` or other *ngIf

[image]

What i'm doing wrong? should i initialize first the `profilo`? if so even by setting `onInit` or in `constructor` the `profilo = new Profilo();` i get the same error of undefined...

If i set a console.log to subscribe it return the right data, so asporto and other stuff from subscribe are not undefined.

As requested here is ProfiloService

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProfiloService {

  public dataProfilo = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private adapter: ProfiloAdapter) { }

  profilo(idNegozio: string): Observable<Profilo>{
    return this.http
    .get(`${Globals.API_URL}/profilo/${idNegozio}`)
    .pipe(map((data: any) => this.adapter.adapt(data)));
  }
}
```

And here is the component where i'm setting the dataProfilo:

```
this.profiloService.dataProfilo.next(profilo);
```

Console.Log from subscribe data

[image]

**EDIT:**

If i add on parent div `*ngIf="profilo.moduli"` it will works fine, but at this point if profilo is undefined w**hy it is not enough to do a simple** `*ngIf="profilo"`?

Comment: Mind sharing relevant code of `ProfiloService`

Comment: Show the service

Comment: @Satpal added the service

Comment: In the `subscribe` can you do `console.log(data)` and please update your question with console data or image of console

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti added the console.log, anyway if in the service i set `BehaviorSubject` to new `BehaviorSubject<any>(new Profilo);` and i will do a `*ngIf="profilo.id"` instead of `*ngIf="profilo"` it will works, but i would a cleaner solution where i have profilo undefined and `*ngIf="profilo"`

Comment: Are you getting any TypeError in console saying Cannot read property asporto of undefined?

Answer (score 1):

In html use ? operator

```
<div *ngIf="profilo?.moduli?.ticketing" ></div>
```

Comment: But why *ngIf="profilo" where profilo is undefined returns error instead of false?

Comment: Is your service returning response? Can you please share your response?

Comment: The service returns the response as if i set a `console.log` to `this.profiloService.dataProfilo.subscribe(data => console.log(data));` it returns all values

Comment: can you plase share your response?

Comment: Does your Profilo interface have asporto ?

Comment: i've just added the console.log, if i set profilo = new Profilo() and i do a *ngIf on profilo.id when it's undefined all works fine, but i can't get why *ngIf="profilo" when whole profilo is undefined is not working

Comment: Try initialize like  => public profilo = {} as any;

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to have an empty array by default and check if it's undefined in the template, I'd recommend you to use [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) with buffer 1 instead. It's similar to `BehaviorSubject` but doesn't need a default value.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProfiloService {
  public dataProfilo = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private adapter: ProfiloAdapter) { }

  profilo(idNegozio: string): Observable<Profilo>{
    return this.http
    .get(`${Globals.API_URL}/profilo/${idNegozio}`)
    .pipe(map((data: any) => this.adapter.adapt(data)));
  }
}
```

Furthermore, if you were to subscribe to an observable in the controller only to use it directly in the template, you might as well use the [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe instead. At the least, it takes care of the unsubscription issue.

Child component

```js
export class ModuliComponent implements OnInit {
  public profilo$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(public profiloService: ProfiloService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.profilo$ = this.profiloService.dataProfilo;
  }

}
```

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(profilo$ | async) as profilo">
  <section>
    ...
  </section>
</ng-container>
```

The template within the `<section>` tags doesn't have to be changed since we are using `*ngIf` directive's `as` signature to denote the current values from the observable.

Answer (score 0):

When init child component then the profilo var is undefine and the profilo var just have data when the API return data. Therefore, u can use "?" operator or check the profilo var as below.

```
<div *ngIf="profilo?.moduli?.ticketing" ></div>
```

OR

```
<div *ngIf="profile && profile.moduli && profile.profile.ticketing" ></div>
```